# Behaviour of Exponents

Tags: exponentiation

Something that many early students, including myself, take for granted is that $$x^\frac{3}{2}=\sqrt{x^3}=(\sqrt{x})^3$$

but is this true? Is exponentiation "commutative" and does a fractional exponent mean the same thing as a root?

Comment: For positive $x$, yes. I advise avoiding the notation $x^a$ if $x$ is not positive and $a$ is not an integer though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not true in general.

You could create pointless results like this.
Take for example $\sqrt{-2}$ which is not definied in $\mathbb{R}$.

But we have that $\sqrt{(-2)^2}=\sqrt{4}=2$, while $(\sqrt{-2})^2$ does not make sense.

Comment: It makes sense, but the result is -2 rather than 2.  There is an intermediate imaginary term.

Answer (score 5):

In the reals it is true that $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}=(a^c)^b$.  This works for all $a \gt 0$ and any real $b,c$, so fractions are included.

It is not true in the complex numbers because there are multiple roots of a number and you need to be careful to pick the correct one.  We avoid the root sign in the complex field for that reason.